# Struts2 tags: get a request attribute whose name is itself a value of another request attribute

Tags: struts2, iterator, ognl

I have a list of table names in a request attribute, "BillSummaryTables". I am iterating through the list and I want to use each table name to get a request attribute for that particular table name. Corresponding to each table name I have another list in request attribute and I want to iterate through that.

This is what I am doing.

```
<s:iterator value='#request.BillSummaryTables' var="tableName" status="itStatus">
<div class="contentbox" role="content">
    <table class="rpt">
    <s:iterator value="#request.get('%{#tableName}').getData()" var="ocRow" status="itStatus">
        <tr style="border:1px solid #CCCCCC">
        <s:iterator value='#ocRow' var="cell" status="itStatus2">
            <td>
            <s:property value="#cell.getValue()"/>
            </td>
        </s:iterator>
        </tr>
    </s:iterator>
        <tr>
        <s:iterator value="#request.get('%{#tableName}').getData()" var="ocTotal">
            <td>
            <s:property value="#ocTotal"/>
            </td>
        </s:iterator>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</div>
</s:iterator>
```

I have also tried

```
#request[<s:property value="#tableName" />].getData()
```

and

```
#request['<s:property value="#tableName" />'].getData()
```

and

```
#request.%{#tableName}
```

But nothing is returned in any case. 
However, this code works fine if I hard code the values. 
i.e. if i use: `#request['other_charges'].getData()`

Note: I am able to retrieve the list of tableName (`#request.BillSummaryTables`).

Comment: Can you show us the request parameters being passed in as a GET request?

Comment: Also it would be good to see the definition of the relevant properties on the action.

Answer (score 2):

**#1)** You are using three nested iterators, but both the first and the second have an instance of IteratorStatus called `itStatus`; they must have different names to work.

**#2)** If the `List`s corresponding to the Table name is, effectively, a List, then you should iterate the list, not the `getData()` stuff (what is that ?)

**#3)**  Why using request ? why not simply using an HashMap on the Action (with the getter), adding elements dynamically using `table name`s as key ?

**#4)** This `#request[<s:property value="#tableName" />].getData()` will obviously not work if put inside another Struts2 tag, like an Iterator (cannot nest Struts2 tags).

However, try something like this (I stripped the second iterator, make it running before, then add stuff), and see if it works (and what it prints):

```
<s:iterator value='#request.BillSummaryTables' var="tableName" status="statusAllTables">
    <div class="contentbox" role="content">

        <br/>==== START DEBUG ====
        <br/>Current table name: [<s:property value="#tableName"/>]
        <br/>Corresponding request object: [<s:property value="#request['%{#tableName}']"/>]
        <br/>getData on that object:   [<s:property value="#request['%{#tableName}'].getData()"/>]
        <br/>===== END DEBUG =====

        <table class="rpt">
            <s:iterator value="#request['%{#tableName}'].getData()" var="ocRow" status="statusThisTable">
                <tr style="border:1px solid #CCCCCC">
                    <s:iterator value='#ocRow' var="cell" status="statusThisField">
                        <td>
                            <s:property value="#cell.getValue()"/>
                        </td>
                    </s:iterator>
                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
        </table>    
    </div>
</s:iterator>
```

**EDIT**

Ok, but then why are you using `request.setAttribute` ? Actions are created per-request... just use a `private List<MyObjects> myObjects` with its getter (`public List<MyObject> getMyObjects()`), and call it from JSP with `<s:iterator value="myObjects">` (in your case, `<s:iterator value="myObjects.data">`.

Please note that `.getData()` in `OGNL` should become `.data` (i didn't noticed it before), removing the get, lowering the first letter of the method, and removing round brackets...

Retry and let us know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrea, but I guess I should put forward my problem in a better way. The BillSummaryTables gives me a list of tables which I want to show. Now suppose the first table name is "other_charges". I have already saved an object called Table in my action using request.setAttribute("other_charges",other_chargesTable).
This object contains some other properties as well as a list which I will get using getData() and then iterate through this list.